# node js with express not loading mongodb database content

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, templates, express

Trying to learn [MongoDB for Node.js](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about)

I've my `app.js`:

```js
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  engines = require('consolidate'),
  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  assert = require('assert');

app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/startup', function(err, db) {

  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    db.collection('startup').find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      res.render('startup', {
        'name': docs
      });
      console.log(docs);

    });

  });

  app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  });

  var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Express server listening on port %s.', port);
  });

});
```

There're documents in the `startup` collection as well:

[image: documents in the startup collection]

And the template file is:

```html
<h1>startups</h1>
{% for s in startup %}
<li><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q={{ s.name }}">{{ s.name }}, {{ s.Founded }}</a>
</li>
{% else %}
<li>No startups found.</li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the result says:

[image: no startups found]

Can someone point me, where am I wrong?

Comment: `for s in name` I guess...

Comment: @Rayon Nope, I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the startups collection as a `name` property, but in a template you try to access it with `startup` identifier for some reason.

Change either and you're good.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zerkms!

Comment: @student – Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the solution which has solved the purpose :)